# How can I check for empty fields in a structure array in Matlab and store all the vectors that are not empty?

Tags: matlab, is-empty

I have a `32x1 struct array`. Each element of this array has several fields. I am trying to check which elements are empty (done), but then I want to create a vector with all the elements that were not empty.

For example I have the `struct array` called `satdata`, from which I want to see if the field `SVID` is empty, so `satdata(i).SVID`. SVID should go from 1 through 32 for my different elements. But if there is a missing element, then it can be `[1:4 6:10 11:32]`.  So I want to create a column vector that is (for this case)

```
[1;2;3;4;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19...32].
```

This is what I have so far:

```
for i = 1:32
    if isempty(satdata(i).SVID)
        continue
    else
    svid = satdata(i).SVID;
     svIdVec(i,:) = svid;
    end
end
```

Which correctly checks for the empty slots, but when I create the vector I get something that looks like `svIdVec = [0,2,3,4...32]`. In this case only the first element is empty.  Therefore I want to get a `31x1` vector such as `[2,3,4...32]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the loop:

```
svIdVec = {satdata.SVID};
[svIdVec{~cellfun(@isempty,svIdVec)}]'; % select only the non-empty values
```

If the SVID field is a vector and you want to aggregate that in a matrix, the following should be used (above code for scalars cannot be used to handle vectors):

```
svIdVec = {satdata.SVID}';
svid = ~cellfun(@isempty,svIdVec );
svIdVec = cell2mat(svIdVec(svid));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in string

```
svIdVec(i,:) = svid;
```

You should replace i here with back of current svIdVec.

Possible solution is

```
svIdVec = [];
for i = 1:32
    if isempty(satdata(i).SVID)
        continue
    else
    svid = satdata(i).SVID;
     svIdVec = [svIdVec, svid];
    end
end
```